# Electron package an app and upload to launchpad ppa

Tags: javascript, electron, software-distribution, launchpad

So, I'm building and packaging a software with electron. Now that I've made the software and got a `.deb` file (in Ubuntu), I want to upload it to my launchpad ppa, so that everyone can easily install/update it. The problem is, ppa doesn't accept `.deb` files directly and I don't know how to package the app so that I can upload it to ppa. There are few question related to this but none of them has the complete guide. So, how do I do this?